# ExtJs combobox store autoload, and typeAhead to load store only when someone type

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs5

this is my combobox

```
{
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        minChars: 3,
                        anchor: '100%',
                        fieldLabel: 'Type',
                        name: 'typeName',
                        emptyText: 'Select Type',
                        valueField: 'id',
                        queryMode: 'local',
                        typeAhead: true,
                        bind: {
                            store: '{type}'
                        }
                    },
```

now the problem is that i have set its store to autolaod, now i want that when someone click on it, it should not load the data from server but when someone type in it than it send request to server
is it possible, is there some property??
help me out

Comment: remove autoLoad from store, set remoteFilter:true on store, remove queryMode:'local' from combo.

Comment: i want combobox autoload true, i have my reasons

Comment: Even though `autoLoad:true` does exactly the opposite of what you want to do. *facepalm* EOD for me here.